# Excel VBA: various ways of selecting a subrange from a range in a UDF

Tags: excel, vba

I have seen on this site various ways of selecting a subrange from a range, and I am struggling to understand the differences.

For the following setup:

[image]

I have the code below :

```
Option Explicit


Function TestX(rg As Range) As Range

    Dim subrg1 As Range, subrg2 As Range, subrg3 As Range

    Set subrg1 = rg.Parent.Range(rg.Cells(4, 4), rg.Cells(9, 10))
    Set subrg2 = Range(Cells(4, 4), Cells(9, 10))
    Set subrg3 = rg.Range(Cells(4, 4), Cells(9, 10))
        
    Debug.Print subrg1.Cells(1).Value, subrg1.Count
    Debug.Print subrg2.Cells(1).Value, subrg2.Count
    Debug.Print subrg3.Cells(1).Value, subrg3.Count
    
End Function
```

and the log is as follows:

```
 16            42 
 1             42 
 16            42
```

What is the difference between these 3 ways ?

I can only make sense of  `subrg2` , which seems to be a straight, absolute way of picking the range`D4:J9`.

Comment: Both `subrg2` and `subrg3` are flawed. When using `Range` or `Cells`, one should qualify the worksheet.

Comment: subrg2 will return the counts for the current sheet, it's probably the least reliable

Comment: Your first and third are relative ranges, i.e. relative to B3 rather than A1.

Comment: @sous2817- I deleted my comment because I think it was wrong, I was thinking there were two different sheet references when they are range references.

Comment: What does 'Parent' do ?

Comment: @VBasic2008 - if the range starts at B3 then `rg.Cells(4, 4)` is E6.

Comment: `Parent` is the worksheet where the range is located

Comment: @ user3203476: It kind of passes the reference to an object on a 'higher' level. In this case, it is the worksheet. Therefore I prefer using `rg.worksheet.Range("Whatever")`. If you want to go 2 levels up to refer to the workbook you cannot use `.Workbook` but only `.Parent` e.g.: `rg.Worksheet.Parent.Close` or `rg.Parent.Parent.Close`.

Comment: I'd use `rg.Cells(2, 3).Resize(6, 7)` since it's closest to how you'd actually describe the sub-range in words, it's anchored to `rg`, and doesn't invoke the parent worksheet.

Comment: @SJR: Sorry, I didn't think it through enough. You are right.

Answer (score -1):

### A Few Ways of Defining a Subrange

- The `getSubRange` function should do what you're asking.
- The `getSubRange2` function would come in handy if the size of the green range may change.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub getSubRangeTEST()
    
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = Range("B3:K10")
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = getSubRange(rg)
    Debug.Print rg.Address, srg.Address
    
    Set srg = getSubRange2(rg)
    If Not srg Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print rg.Address, srg.Address
    End If

End Sub

Function getSubRange(rg As Range) As Range
    
    Const rRows As Long = 6
    Const rCols As Long = 7
    Const oRows As Long = 1
    Const oCols As Long = 2
    
    If Not rg Is Nothing Then
        With rg
            Set getSubRange = .Offset(oRows, oCols).Resize(rRows, rCols)
            'Set getSubRange = .Offset(1, 2).Resize(6, 7) ' without the constants
            'Set getSubRange = .Cells(oRows + 1, oCols + 1).Resize(rRows, rCols)
            'Set getSubRange = .Cells(2, 3).Resize(6, 7) ' without the constants
        End With
    End If

End Function

Function getSubRange2(rg As Range) As Range
    
    Const rRows As Long = 2
    Const rCols As Long = 3
    Const oRows As Long = 1
    Const oCols As Long = 2
    
    If Not rg Is Nothing Then
        With rg
            On Error Resume Next
            Set getSubRange2 = .Resize(.Rows.Count - rRows, _
                .Columns.Count - rCols).Offset(oRows, oCols)
            'Set getSubRange2 = .Resize(.Rows.Count - 2, _
                .Columns.Count - 3).Offset(1, 2) ' without the constants
            On Error GoTo 0
        End With
    End If

End Function
```